# How should I store page and subpage in collection with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create simple CMS with the ability to add new pages to the site. I have currently created a Collection called `Pages`:

```
var PageSchema = new Schema({
    name_en: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name_nl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug_en:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug_nl:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content_en: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content_nl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    visible: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 1
    },
    is_headMenu: {
        type: Number,
        require: true,
        default: 0
    },
    is_footerMenu: {
        type: Number,
        require: true,
        default: 0
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

});
```

This collection store all pages, but after a few days I needed to add an option to also store sub-pages to existing pages. 
I was thinking of creating an object inside of the Page Schema to hold all the sub-pages.

Like this:

```
    var subPage = new Schema({
    name_nl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name_en: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug_en:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug_nl:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content_en: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content_nl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    visible: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 1
    }

});
var PageSchema = new Schema({
    name_en: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    name_nl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug_en:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    slug_nl:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content_en: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    content_nl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    visible: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 1
    },
    is_headMenu: {
        type: Number,
        require: true,
        default: 0
    },
    is_footerMenu: {
        type: Number,
        require: true,
        default: 0
    },
    subPages: [
        subPage
    ],
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

});
```

But I cant use it because after creating a `Page` I'm required to fill the object 'subPage' because it's required. I don't want that. I want to add them whenever I want, and this way its not possible. How should I do it properly?

Comment: Referencing of schema should work! One-to-many Relationship. One page can have many sub-pages. So create sub-pages and store their object ids in PageSchema. It should work! for more info check http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Yes but I want to create those subpages only if I chose checkbox "Make as subpage" I'm using 'Require: true'  so even If i create head Page I'm required to give subpage as well otherwise I get I error saying for example 'name_nl is required' .I want to be able to leave Object with subpages empty if Im creating Headpage